# Tabulator - Download file keeping the original Javascript structure

Tags: javascript, web-applications, download, web-development-server, tabulator

I am using Tabulator for the development of an interactive web page and I am facing some issues with the **File download**.
Basically, I would like to do the download of the table in **Javascript format**. It means that I am loading a Javascript table into the web page, the user has the possibility to interact and change some values in the table and to **Save** the changes. When clicking "Save", I would like to download a file which has to be the same of the Javascript I loaded initially (but, of course, with the values changed by the user).

On the Tabulator website I found only the possibility to perform the saving/download in CSV, HTML, XLSX, JSON and PDF, not in **Javascript**.

To download the data in CSV, for instance, it is possible to do:
`table.download("csv", "data.csv")`
I am wondering if there is something like:
`table.download("js", "data.js")`

The solution that I am trying to implement is to create my custom **file formatter**, which can solve the issue but I was wondering if there is a more elegant and easy solution, since I need to handle different situations because I am using different table structures (nested, grouped, ...).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Not sure if it can be done with tabulator out of the box, but have you considered using [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable)?

Comment: @FiddlingAway  the problem is that the user can modify a cell on the Tabulator table and this change has to be saved on a server, that's why I am trying to download the file.
Do you think that I can use the "contenteditable" attribute in this situation? If yes, how?
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: If you want just to change the table, and save it locally (change the cell content, click on a button, save the table as a CSV or an XLSX), `contenteditable`  should be enough. However, if you want the change to be saved on the server (you should add this to your question), you would need to use AJAX. Depending on the structure of your table, there are various ways of doing this. Unfortunately, without seeing relevant parts of your code, I can't offer a more substantial suggestion.

Comment: @FiddlingAway I didn't mention that I wanna save the file on a server because I already handled it, I do it in PHP actually.
I tried to download and reuse a CSV file but the it started to become a mess because the files loaded initially, when the user opens the page, are in Javascript, since they are generated by a back-end script in this way. 
About the `contenteditable`,  do you think that I could for instance add this attribute by using something like `cell.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true")`? My doubt remains how to save this in a Javascript structured file

Answer (score 0):

At the end I decided to proceed creating a custom file formatter to generate a Javascript file.
The code is:

```
//custom file formatter
var jsFileFormatter = function(list, options, setFileContents, mimeType){
  //list - an array of export rows representing one row of data for the table;
  //options - the options object passed from the download function
  //setFileContents - function to call to pass the formatted data to the downloader

  var fileContents = [];
  var first_row = true;
  var jsConstructorFields = ["  {field1:\"", "\", field2:\"", "\", field3:\"", "\", field4:\"", "\", field5:\"", "\", field6:\""];

  fileContents.push("var tabledata = [\n");
  //iterate over rows
  list.forEach((row) => {
    var item = [];
    var field_cnt = 0;

    if (first_row==false) {
      //iterate over the columns in a row
      row.columns.forEach((col) => {
          if(col){
              item.push(jsConstructorFields[field_cnt]);
              item.push(col.value);
              field_cnt++
          }
      });

      // End of row
      item.push("\"},\n");
      fileContents.push(item.join(''));
    } else {
      first_row=false;
    }
  });

  fileContents.push("];");
  //trigger file download, passing the formatted data and mime type
  setFileContents(fileContents, "text/plain");
}
```

The download using this formatter can be triggered using:

```
  table.download(jsFileFormatter, "file.js");
```